Sub - $C^*$-algebra $C^* (a)$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ generated by an element $ a \in A $.
Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and, let $a \in A$.
I have some questions that may appear for you very naive, but i'm not very strong in operator algebra.
1 - What does it mean that $C^*(a) \subset A$ is the $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$ generated by $a \in A$ ?
2 - How can we express the elements of $C^*(a)$ ?
3 - Is $ C^* (a) $ a free $ C^* $-algebra ?
4 - Can we formulate the object $C^*(a)$ as a solution of a universal property ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

looking at your post history I think I know less than you about $C^\ast$-algebras, but the $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $a$ is the smallest $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $A$ containing $a$. You can prove that $\overline {{p(a, a^\ast) : p \text { is a polynomial in two variables without a constant term}}}$ is a $C^\ast$-subalgebra (closed $\ast$-subalgebra) of $A$ that contains $a$, and you can conversely show that any $C^\ast$-subalgebra containing $a$ also contains $\overline {{p(a, a^\ast) : p \text { is a polynomial in two variables without a constant term}}}$.

(if $A$ is unital, then you can get a unital subalgebra by allowing a non-zero constant term for $p$. Also, $\overline {{\ldots}}$ means closure here) - not sure what "free" means here and not sure about q4 either.

Thank you.  :-D . No problem about q3 and q4. you say, $p$ is a polynomial in $2$ variables. Is $p$ belongs to $ \mathbb{C} [X,Y] $, or to $  \mathbb{C} \langle X,Y \rangle $ ? Thank you again.

One other question : You say that $ \overline{{ \dots }} $ means closure here, but this closure is relative to which $ C^* $ - norm ?

Let's go all the way back to just talking about rings. Given a ring $A$ and an element $a \in A$ we can consider the subring $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ of $A$ generated by $a$. This can be defined in the following equivalent ways:

It is the subring obtained by starting from $a$ and "repeatedly adding, subtracting, and multiplying" (this can be formalized but it's a bit annoying and other equivalent definitions are easier to work with anyway; but this is the precise sense in which the subring is being generated by $a$).
It is the subring of $A$ consisting of expressions of the form $f(a)$, where $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is any polynomial.
It is the image of the natural homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to A$ sending $x$ to $a$.
It is the intersection of all subrings of $A$ containing $a$.

This is just four different ways of saying "the smallest subring containing $a$." The same definitions apply to the subring generated by any number $a_1, a_2, \dots$ elements of $A$; we only need to be careful that if $A$ is noncommutative we need to replace the polynomial rings in definitions 2 and 3 with noncommutative polynomials. Note that in definition 3 $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ is the image of a homomorphism from a free ring, and not itself a free ring; this homomorphism can fail to be injective, for example if $a = 1$. So the notation may be slightly confusing, but as far as I know it's pretty standard.
Now let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra. We would like to discuss the $C^{\ast}$-subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[a]$ of $A$ generated by $a \in A$. Here the natural definition is that a $C^{\ast}$-subalgebra should be a complex $^{\ast}$-subalgebra which is also closed with respect to the norm of $A$. This complicates the definition of what it means to generate such a thing but not by too much. We can give the following equivalent definitions:

It is the $C^{\ast}$-subalgebra obtained by starting from $a$ and "repeatedly adding, multiplying, scalar multiplying, taking adjoints, and taking limits" (again, this can be formalized but it's very annoying, since it's not clear how many times we need to do this).
It is the closure of the $^{\ast}$-subalgebra generated by $a$ (wrt the norm of $A$); explicitly this consists of expressions of the form $f(a, a^{\dagger})$ where $f \in \mathbb{C} \langle x, y \rangle$ is a noncommutative polynomial in two variables (if you don't require units then this polynomial should have no constant term), as George says in the comments. If $a$ is normal you can use commutative polynomials here.
It is the intersection of all $C^{\ast}$-subalgebras containing $a$.

There is no easy analogue of definition 3 above anymore, because there are no free $C^{\ast}$-algebras on an element with no relations. (In particular $\mathbb{C}[a]$ is not a free $C^{\ast}$-algebra, because there aren't any free $C^{\ast}$-algebras.) I think there ought to be a free $C^{\ast}$-algebra on an element of norm $\le r$ (so we can take $r = \| a \|$), but if it isn't required to be normal this thing is noncommutative and I have no idea if it has a more explicit description so I don't think this is very useful anyway.
It is possible to think of this as the solution to a universal problem: namely, there is a poset of $C^{\ast}$-subalgebras containing $a$, and we are looking for a least element of it. (If it exists it must be the intersection of all elements; this is a nice exercise.) In category-theoretic terms this is an initial object. The same applies to the subring generated by an element (and much more generally, to subgroups, submodules, etc).

Thank you very much Sir for this clean answer.  :-D Goerge,above, said that $ \overline{{ \dots }} $ means closure, but do you know to which $ C^* $ - norm is relative this closure ? Thank you very much.  :-)

@YoYo12: there's only one $C^{\ast}$-norm available, namely the one in $A$.

Thank you very much Sir. :-)

There is a free $C^\ast$-algebra generated by an (not necessarily normal) element $a$ of norm $\leq r$. Namely, you can take the free $\ast$-algebra $\mathbb{C}\langle a, a^\dagger\rangle$ and complete it with respect to the norm $|\cdot| = \sup_\pi |\pi(\cdot)|$, where $\pi$ ranges over all $\ast$-homomorphisms from $\mathbb{C}\langle a, a^\dagger\rangle$ to a $C^\ast$-algebra that sends $a$ to an element of norm at most $r$. It is “free” as it is the left adjoint to the “forgetful functor” that sends a $C^\ast$-algebra to its closed ball of radius $r$ around the origin.

Similarly, you can define various “free” $C^\ast$-algebras so long as there are norm constraints (implicit or explicit) on all of the generators. As you said, though, there aren’t really any “explicit” descriptions of these $C^\ast$-algebras (unless you count my construction above as “explicit”). The one closest to being explicit is probably the free (necessarily unital, as we’re dealing with unitaries) $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $\kappa$ many unitaries, which is $C^\ast(\mathbb{F}\kappa)$, the full $C^\ast$-algebra of the free group $\mathbb{F}\kappa$ on $\kappa$ many generators.

(But then again, the full $C^\ast$-algebra of a group is also the completion of the group ring w.r.t. a norm that’s defined via universal property rather than explicitly, so it’s up to interpretation whether this really counts as an “explicit” description.)

(Since I’m a von Neumann algebraists, let me just make a tangential remark that there are even “free” $W^\ast$-algebras. For example, the free $W^\ast$-algebra generated by a single element of norm $\leq r$ is the double dual of the free $C^\ast$-algebra generated by a single element of norm $\leq r$, and so on. Unfortunately, this has the effect of even making the commutative case “non-explicit”, since it’s not exactly easy to describe what is, say, $C([-r, r])^{\ast\ast}$.)

(If restricting to closed balls is a bit weird for a “forgetful functor”, one can also define a free $C^\ast$-algebra over a Banach space, in which case it is actually the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $C^\ast$-algebras and $\ast$-homomorphisms to Banach spaces and contractive linear maps. Then the free $C^\ast$-algebra generated by an element of norm $\leq r$ can be understood as the free $C^\ast$-algebra over the Banach space $\mathbb{C}$ - with the norm on $\mathbb{C}$ scaled by $r$.)
